# ApplePay error `Connection to remote alert view service failed` on iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, applepay, passkit

I have a fully working implementation of ApplePay. all works well on iOS10, 11 and 12.

Since the first beta of iOS 13 and Xcode 11 and up until now (iOS13GM and Xcode 11GM) the ApplePay authorization modal doesn't show up.

My `PKPaymentRequest` should be fine because it works on previous OS versions, and when I'm trying to present  the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` I get this in the console:

```
[General] Connection to remote alert view service failed
```

I looked at other questions and tried to turn ApplePay capabilities off and back on several times, hard cleans, restarts. 
I even created a new app with a new merchant ID and certificate, and still got the same results - worked on iOS 12 and **didn't** on iOS 13GM.

**UPDATE:**

Everything works as expected using Xcode 11GM, running on iOS 12.2 simulator.
same code on iOS 13GM simulator doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution Tal? Having the same issue and similar ios versions.

Comment: @vcazkonzam Didn't find a solution but I managed to test it on a real device and it works. Still not working on iOS13 simulators for me (Official Xcode 11 and iOS13).

Comment: Still broken on Xcode 11.1 / iOS 13.1 simulator.

Comment: Just tested on Xcode 11.2 beta 2 and it's working again 

Comment: Work on Xcode 11.1 and Simulator 12.4